# How can I programmatically create a transactional proxy?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I created a bean instance with

```
Type instance = new Type();
```

and autowired it using

```
ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(instance);
```

The beans run method is executed by a `ThreadPoolTaskExecuter` and is annotated with the 
`@Transactional` annotation which has no effect in this case. Since lazy loading problems occur. I need a transaction here.

How can I create a transactional proxy and wrap my instance?

Is there a way other than using transaction-manager manually?

Comment: Can't you define Type as a prototype bean and look it up from the context?  That would be the simplest way to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the correct proxy if you [apply BeanPostProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) from the context:

```
instance = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(instance);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly create a `PlatformTransactionManager` subclass manually and use its methods to create and commit or rollback transactions.

If you want to proxy an object, the class you probably want is `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean`. Setup an instance of that and call `getObject()` to get your proxied class.